# Why am I getting "Unknown server tag 'vbp:RegularExpressionValidatorItem'" here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, runtime-error

First and foremost, this is an ASP.NET **Website** project. I can't change that, and it makes my heart ache because of it, but I'll have to deal with it.

Now, I have a `tagPrefix` defined in my `web.config` like this:

```
<add tagPrefix="vbp" namespace="MyNamespace" />
```

and that allows me to reference this class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class RegularExpressionValidatorItem
    {
```

in markup like this:

```
<vbp:DataRowTextBox ID="EMail" runat="server" Label="E-mail" MaxLength="50"
    IsRequired="true" RequiredErrorMessage="Please enter your email address.">
    <Regexes>
        <vbp:RegularExpressionValidatorItem Type="Email" />
    </Regexes>
</vbp:DataRowTextBox>
```

and this works **fantastic** in development, but when I deploy it to our INTG environment it fails with the following error:

```
Exception Source: System.Web
Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException
Exception Message: Unknown server tag 'vbp:RegularExpressionValidatorItem'.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)
   at System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)
   at System.Web.UI.CollectionBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)
   at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
```

**Unfortunately**, that's all I get. Why would this behave differently when deployed to IIS?

Comment: Have you deployed the assembly with RegularExpressionValidatorItem ?

Comment: @Max, there is no real assembly per say, it's a Website project, so the `bin` folder doesn't even contain an assembly with that class -it's compiled on the fly and placed in a temporary folder. That's why I could only use the `namespace` reference because I don't know the name of the assembly that gets built.

Comment: @Max, you were right friend. See my answer. It's a mess to get the assembly name, but it is required on a deployed website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, I'll admit, surprised me. In development the assembly **cannot** be included in the `Web.config` because there isn't one. It's inferred. But when deployed an assembly **must be** included in this line:

```
<add tagPrefix="vbp" namespace="MyNamespace" assembly="MyAssembly" />
```

The pain of it all is that I needed to get to the published folder to know the name of the assembly. It's cool now because I know the name of the assembly, but man, c'mon, this is why it's so much better to use web applications vs. websites.

At any rate, that's the answer. Until next time friends ... happy coding!